# addAttributeToFilter with dropdown not filtering result

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute

I have attribute named `addAttributeToFilter` with two drop-down values:  "yes", "no"

```
public function getDefaultRecommendation() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('default_recommendation', 1);
    Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
    return $collection;
}
```

It displays all the products instead of just product with 'yes' dropdown value.

Answer (score 0):

Arun, yo need to fetch attribute yes option then filter the collection.

```
$yesOpID=null;
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'default_recommendation');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach($options as $e){
        if($e['label']=='Yes'):
        $yesOpID=$e['value'];
        endif;
    }
}
```

then

```
 $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('default_recommendation', yesOpID);
```

**From**

```
 $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

**To**

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',array('in',array(3,4)));
```

Also you need to  put `store id`  to `addStoreFilter`() function

```
 $currentStoreId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
 addStoreFilter($currentStoreId)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering amit, still displaying all the products. Pasted your code after `code`  $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()); `code`

Comment: Wait. I will give u solution

Comment: I have changed dropdown to yes or  no

Comment: I have update my answer